# How to access dynamically-generated page content via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint web part page with a list view that is grouped and defaulted to "collapsed" (much like a basic toggle). SharePoint generates its own JavaScript to handle the initial click action, which then expands the page area and dynamically writes new content to that area. The problem is that jQuery cannot access the new content immediately following the click (it needs to finish loading). My thoughts are to add a 2nd jQuery click function to the toggle link and somehow wait for the new content to be added before anything else happens, but I'm not sure how to determine when the dynamic content finishes loading...

```
        //bind a 2nd additional onclick handler via jquery to these items
        $('td.ms-gb').children('a').click(function() 
            { 
                //give the clicked item a border for visual identification
                $(this).css("border","1px solid cyan");

                //delay this function until the sharepoint onclick handler finishes loading new content
                $('TD.ms-vb-icon').children('a').each(function(index) 
                   {
                        //give each item a border for visual identification 
                        $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
                        //perform more jquery on each item

                   }
                );         

            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

A common technique to address this kind of issues is to use

> setTimeout(function, timeoutInMs)

and try to find new content in function, if fail restart a timeout until you find the content

Here's a jsFiddle to illustrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dhww2/

Comment: yeah, i thought about that, but i'm not very good with JavaScript.

Comment: so, is this possible... setTimeout(jQuery function, timeoutInMs)?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to set another click handler that registers with `$.ajaxSuccess()` http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/  and responds after the first AJAX request (after the click) finishes

It's hackish, but if the code that is fetching the dynamic content doesn't have a callback, there aren't many options.

Comment: I wonder if $.ajaxSuccess() works for AJAX not invoked by jQuery functions.

Comment: @gertas: I don't think it does, but SharePoint's code is written in jQuery

Comment: AFAIK SharePoint doesn't ship jQuery, I think you meant "JScript". [2010 source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/publicsector/archive/2010/06/28/does-jquery-ship-with-sharepoint-2010-and-why-you-should-be-using-an-ajax-cdn.aspx)

Comment: it's MOSS2007, so the SharePoint "toggle" code is NOT using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

What are you going to do with loaded contnent? Just style and catch another clicks?

In such case use stylesheets for custom styling and jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to catch (click) events of further loaded elements.

**Update for comment**

```
$('TD.ms-vb-icon a').live('click', function(ev) {
    $(this).attr('name','value');
}
```

May not work if your click tracking code registers earlier. If so try with `mouseover` event.

Comment: with the loaded content, i only need to append a name attribute to the anchor tags.

Comment: Ok, so you eventually you want to jump to these named anchors?

Comment: nope, just need to run some jquery to append a name attribute to each of the anchor tags of each of the returned items.

Comment: think of this like a basic toggle... you click to expand and new content is loaded in the space below. i only need to append a name attribute to the anchor tag of each item that is loaded. but i can't figure out how to write the jquery to find the loaded items.

Comment: Right, but I try to understand what is purpose of these "name" attributes. If loaded content may receive another click then you can catch it by `live` and fill missing "names" in event handler. Even 'mouseenter' or 'focus' could be used.

Comment: long story, but the name attribute is required for our link tracking application. the loaded content is a list of links with NO name attribute. so i need to find the loaded list of links AFTER they load so that i can use the .attr() function to append the new name values.

Comment: can you provide a code snippet using .live() function that would accomplish what i'm trying to do?